# innerHTML showing blank even though element has a value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function called function `getContactsToForm()`;
This function runs on a div row called results that holds the values from my sql. On click each row is supposed to load this function grab the data from `li[0]` and pass it on to the rest of the function. 
I seem to be getting it to work all right, however the `Li`'s show up empty on my console log even though the table is populated. I assume that means that the sequencing is wrong. 
Previously I had a working sample that had everything it table rows. The original function commented out would use the `Tr` tags and grab the value. The function was called within the `getContacts()` function and it all worked well, with the `LI` I am having trouble. Any thoughts?

functions.js

```js
// JavaScript Document
//formoverlay

function formSubmit() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'contactsinsert.php',
    data: $('#frmBox').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#success').html(response);
    }
  });
  var form = document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
  window.location.reload();
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#srchbtn').click(function start() {
    getContacts();
  });
});

function getContacts() {
  var txtsearch = $('#txtsearch').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'contactstable.php',
    type: "POST",
    //dataType: "json",
    data: ({
      txtsearch: txtsearch
    }),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#displayContacts').html(response);
      //addRowHandlers();
      //getContactsToForm();
    }
  });

}
window.onload = getContacts();


/*function addRowHandlers() {
 console.log("hi");
        var table = document.getElementById("resultstable");
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("li");
        console.log(rows[0]);
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         var currentRow = table.rows[i];
         console.log(currentRow);         
         var createClickHandler = function(row) {
            return function() { 
             */
function getContactsToForm() {
  var table = document.getElementById("resultstable");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("ul")['results'];
  console.log(rows);
  var lis = table.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];

  console.log(lis);


  var id = lis.innerHTML;
  console.log(id);
  //alert("id:" +id);
  document.getElementById("id").value = id;



  $.ajax({
    url: "inputtest.php",
    success: function(result) {
      var frm = document.getElementById("frmBox2");
      var ID = document.getElementById("id").value;

      if (/\S/.test(ID)) {
        ajax_request(this.action, {
          "action": "fetch",
          "ID": ID
        }, process_response);
      } else {
        alert("No ID supplied");
      }

      function ajax_request(url, data, callback) {
        var i, parts, xhr;
        // if data is an object, unroll as HTTP post data (a=1&b=2&c=3 etc.)
        if (typeof data == "object") {
          parts = [];
          for (i in data) {
            parts.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[i]));
          }
          data = parts.join("&");
        }
        // create an XML HTTP Request object
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr) {
          // set a handler for changes in ready state
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              // check for HTTP status of OK
              if (xhr.status == 200) {
                try {
                  callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                } catch (e) {
                  console.log(xhr.responseText); // for debug
                  alert("AJAX request incomplete:\n" + e.toString());
                }
              } else {
                alert("AJAX request failed: " + xhr.status);
              }
            }
          };
          // open connection and send payload
          xhr.open("GET", "inputtest.php" + "?" + data, true);
          xhr.send(null);
        }
      }
      /**
       * process the response, populating the form fields from the JSON data
       * @param {Object} response the JSON data parsed into an object
       */
      function process_response(response) {
        var frm = document.getElementById("frmBox2");
        var i;
        console.dir(response); // for debug
        for (i in response) {
          if (i in frm.elements) {
            frm.elements[i].value = response[i];
          }
        }
      }


    }
  });

};


// currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
//       }
//       }
//window.onload = addRowHandlers();



function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  window.location.reload();

}


function openCon() {
  document.getElementById("conNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeCon() {
  document.getElementById("conNav").style.width = "0%";
  var form = document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();

}

function enablebuttons() {
  document.getElementById("insert").disabled = false;


}
```

```html
contactstable.php (calls the mysql and receives contacts)
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
include_once "iud.php";

$arrayval = array();
$search=$_POST['txtsearch'];
$search1 = explode(" ", $search);
array_push($arrayval, $search1);

foreach ($arrayval as $val){
    $orIndex = checkOr($val);
    if(empty($orIndex)){
        $resultstable = getResults($val);
        $resultstable1 = buildTable($resultstable);
        print($resultstable1);
    }else{
        print"there is an or here";
        $resultstable = getResults($orIndex);

        $resultstable1 = buildTable($resultstable);
        print($resultstable1);
    }
}

buildTable($resultstable);
/*if (empty($orIndex)){
  print "no or";
  $resultstable = getResults($val);
  $resultstable1 = buildTable($resultstable);
  print $resultstable1; 

  function getResults($array){
  include_once "iud.php";
  $db = connectDatabase();

  $totalResults = array();

  $length = count($array);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
  $outputDisplay = "";  
  $myrowcount = 0;
  $sql_statement  = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, pcat, position, state ";
  //, congroup, cattype, company, position, email, website, phone, mphone, wphone, fax, add1, add2, city, state, zip, country, reference, entrydate, enteredby, notes ";
  $sql_statement .= "FROM contacts ";
  $sql_statement .= "WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$array[$i]%' or lastname LIKE '%$array[$i]%')"; 
  $sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname";
  $sqlResults = selectResults($db, $sql_statement);
  $error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];

  if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
  {
  $outputDisplay .= "<br />Error on DB";
  $outputDisplay .= $error_or_rows;
  } else {

  $totalResults = array_merge($totalResults, $sqlResults);
  //$totalResults = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $totalResults)));
  $arraySize = $error_or_rows;
  }
  }
  //return $totalResults;
  //print $arraySize;
  //print_r($error_or_rows);
  return $totalResults;
  }

  function buildTable($totalResults){
  include_once "iud.php";
  $outputDisplay = "";
  //$outputDisplay .= '<table id="resultstable" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
  //$outputDisplay .= '<tr><th align="left">ID</th><th align="left" width="30%">First Name</th><th align="left" width="30%">Last Name</th><th align="left" width="30%">Pages Category</th><th align="left" width="30%">Position</th><th align="left" width="30%">state</th></tr>';
  $outputDisplay .= '<div id="resultstable">';
  $outputDisplay .= '<div id="headers">';
  $outputDisplay .= '<ul id="headers">';
  $myrowcount = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i < count($totalResults); $i++)
  {
  $myrowcount++;
  $contactid = $totalResults[$i]['id'];
  $firstname = $totalResults[$i]['firstname'];
  $lastname = $totalResults[$i]['lastname'];
  $pcat     = $totalResults[$i]['pcat'];
  $position     = $totalResults[$i]['position'];
  $state     = $totalResults[$i]['state'];

  $outputDisplay .= '<ul id="results">';
  $outputDisplay .='<li>'.$contactid.'</li>';
  $outputDisplay .= '<li><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon();getContactsToForm();">'.$firstname.'</span></li>';
  $outputDisplay .= '<li><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$lastname.'</span></li>';
  $outputDisplay .= '<li><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$pcat.'</span></li>';
  $outputDisplay .= '<li><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$position.'</span></li>';
  $outputDisplay .= '<li><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$state.'</span></li>';

  $outputDisplay .= '</ul>';
  //echo $myrowcount;

  }

  $outputDisplay .= "</div>";

  return $outputDisplay;


  }



  function checkOr($searchArray){
  if (in_array("OR",$searchArray)){
  $orPos = array_search("OR", $searchArray);
  //$surrVal =array();
  //$surrVal = array(--$orPos, ++$orPos);
  if (!empty($orPos)){ 
  $surrVal = "";
  $surrVal = --$orPos;
  $orValArray = array();
  array_push($orValArray,$searchArray[$surrVal]);
  $surrVal = $orPos+2;
  array_push($orValArray,$searchArray[$surrVal]);
  return $orValArray;


  }


  }
  }
```

The results I get are:

209

Anis

Baker

DC

but from the console side:
[image]

Comment: Please remove everything from your code that's not relevant to the issue (like the 50% that's commented out) You should also be consistent with indenting your code. It's really hard to follow the flow as it is right now.

Comment: You can't use Stack Snippets for PHP code.

Comment: How does this code work at all with the definition of `buildTable()` commented out?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to put function definitions inside `if` statements. If you do this, you can't call the function before it's defined, because PHP can't tell whether the condition will be true or not until you get to it.

Comment: You should target one environment at a time. If your issue is with the PHP, reduce it to the minimum PHP code and provide expected and actual results. If your issue is at the client, reduce it to the minimum javascript and provide example response text from the AJAX calls.